# How can I conceal the underside of roof sheathing with protruding roofing nails?

Tags: paint, roofing, carport

I just had a new roof done and as you can see, they used long nails which protruded through the plywood and splintered the wood. I cannot afford to have someone scrape and paint the whole underside of the carport. Can I just have someone spray the whole thing as a quick fix?[image: undersideofcarport]

Comment: FYI, it's normal (and required by shingle manufacturers) that roofing nails protruded like that for suitable grip. The mistake the roofers made was in not informing you of this before they began considering your painted ceiling, which is a matter of professionalism and not technique.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation one time and the carpenters just put a sheathing over it to hide everything.  The sheathing was no thicker that wood paneling and finished very nicely after painting.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me once. At first I was unhappy because the nails poked though, but then as vin944 stated, its proper for them to protrude through. I talked to the roofers and they gave me some 1/4 in. sheathing. I laid them all out flat on the driveway, painted them, then nailed them up with some help. It looked much better and gave it a finished look.